# Animate the size of a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website for college and I have a table with data. I am prompted to implement some javascript functionality to it as the project is based on our learning of php and mysql. I planned to use javascript to make it so when I hover over a row of data its size increases (animation) but I don't know how to do it.

I'd also like it when I mouse leave it, it shrinks back to its original size.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<?php
  require_once("connect.php");

  $query = "SELECT * FROM player";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $stmt->closeCursor();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Players</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
        <h1>Players</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="30px" align="center">
          <tr>
            <th>Player ID</th>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Player Age</th>
            <th>Player Team</th>
          </tr>
          <?php foreach ($results as $r): ?>
          <tr id="row">
            <td><?php echo $r['ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r['Player Name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r['Player Age']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r['Player Team']; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.btn:active {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#btn1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#btn2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#btn3 {
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../resources/img/football.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

JS

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');

var row = document.getElementById('row');

row.onmouseenter = function() {
  row.style.scale = "2";
}

row.onmouseleave = function() {
  row.style.scale = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it using JavaScript, you will first have to use classes on your rows, instead of ids. That is because the rows are created using a loop. So the same id would be defined to all the rows... And that is not good. In an HTML document, an `id` must be unique.

Then, you have to select those rows using [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), which return a collection of elements... Not just a single one. Well... There may be just one, but it will be in an array.

In order to bind some events to the rows, you have to iterate the collection array and add an event listener to it. That is done with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

And finally, the scaling is done using the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property.

Here is your code with only two rows... I "simulated" your PHP results from database.

Good luck explaining it all... Click on the links and read the documentation. That's the best way to learn something.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');

var row = document.getElementsByClassName('row');

for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

  row[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
    this.style.transform = "scale(1.2)";
  });

  row[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
    this.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.btn:active {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#btn1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#btn2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#btn3 {
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../resources/img/football.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Players</h1>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="30px" align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>Player ID</th>
      <th>Player Name</th>
      <th>Player Age</th>
      <th>Player Team</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row">
      <td>32</td>
      <td>Golem</td>
      <td>472</td>
      <td>Badass</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="row">
      <td>79</td>
      <td>Kharmesh</td>
      <td>124</td>
      <td>Cold Bloods</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do it with css transitions.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/scale-on-hover-with-webkit-transition/

```css
tr { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
tr:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>One</td><tr>
<tr><td>Two</td><tr>
<tr><td>Three</td><tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you I was aware that was possible and it's a great solution. Although I was hoping to do it via javascript because as I said, we get bonus marks for implementing some javascript functionality like this.